# Substituir palavras erradas num Campo de Texto

Tags: javascript, string, input, while, for

Queria uma idéia de como criar algo do tipo, campo de texto, onde digitamos alguma palavra(s) errada e logo é corrigida(s).

*Por exemplo:*

```
<body><input type="text" id="exibir" onkeyup="troca()"/></body>

<script language="javascript">
 function troca() {
 var str =   document.getElementById("exibir").value; 
 var res = str.replace(/case/gi, "casa");
 document.getElementById("exibir").value = res;
 }
</script>
```

> *Antes:* `case`
>
> *Depois:* `casa`
>
> Hipótese - Aqui um script inteligente por traz do campo de texto, o corrigi ou melhor a substitui `case` por `casa`. Digamos que este script pegou algo próximo da palavra digitada e exibi na sua forma correta.

Comment: a `input` é usada para entrada de dados(login, senha, e-mail, etc), são dados que não tem como dizer se estão certos ou errados. mas o `textarea` já possui o o corretor ortográfico, talvez seja melhor no que você precisa.

Comment: Solução que depende de um dicionário de palavras em Português: https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-auto-correct

Comment: O critério para saber se uma palavra está correta, ou não, é meio complicado, você vai ter que ter um dicionário completo, no teu script, eu acho que mesmo fazendo uma "busca binária", vai dar um delay bem grande (pois é letra por letra), isso só para checar se o que o cara digitou, está correto. Acho que você deveria repensar se isso é mesmo viável. Outros sistemas que fazem isso, provavelmente tem cache de palavras mais comum, e IA que permite prever as possíveis próximas palavra, baseado no que o cara digitou antes. Isso é bem complexo para um simples mortal programador fazer sozinho

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Bom Pessoal, este script foi idealizado com base em erros grotescos da gramatica comumente utilizado no dia-a-dia, tanto na ponta dos dedos e na ponta da língua. Às vezes, nem existem nos dicionários ou têm significado completamente diferente do que se está querendo dizer. São palavras que costumamos ouvir e que estão completamente erradas. Minha Programação foi realizada com sucesso, do que tinha em mente, após vasta pesquisa. Veja :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Correcao Ortografica/Gramatica</title>
<style>

.campo
{
width:320px;
padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;  
border: 1px solid #f1f1f1f;
font-family: "lucida", tahoma, arial, verdana;
font-size: 12pt;
color: #111;
}

.outer
{
text-align: center;
width: 75%; 
font-size: 14pt;
}

.inner
{
border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 61%;
text-align: left;
font-size: 12pt;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>

<h2>Alguns erros de português que você nem sabia que estava cometendo ...</h2>

<input type="text" onkeyup="corrigir(this.value)" id="txt" class="campo"/>


<hr width=70% color=whitesmoke size=1 darshed/>

<div class="outer">Digite alguma(s) Palavra abaixo no Campo acima:
<div class="inner">
<p>supérfluo</p>
<p>locaute</p>
<p>gaviota</p>
<p>guspir</p>
<p>holoforte</p>
<p>imbigo</p>
<p>luvem</p>
<p>estupro</p>
<p>bulância</p>
<p>bassoura</p>
<p>encostamento</p>
<p>escângalo</p>
<p>helecoptro</p>
<p>ebisódio</p>
<p>camioneiro</p>
<p>iplisom</p>
<p>trabesseiro</p>
<p>trabisseiro</p>
<p>dico</p>
<p>repescagem</p>
<p>garfanhoto</p>
<p>dibre</p>
<p>tabua</p>
<p>falcudade</p>
<p>experiênça</p>
<p>asterístico</p>
<p>subaco</p>
<p>gumerangue</p>
<p>tevelisão</p>
<p>cisnei</p>
<p>prósta</p>
<p>resitro</p>
<p>sigura</p>
<p>fervereiro</p>
<p>congustivel</p>
<p>onegaro</p>
<p>mictorio</p>
<p>degote</p>
<p>resistro</p>
<p>bigalha</p>
<p>guspe</p>
<p>delatavam</p>
<p>rejuvenescimento</p>
<p>vasculante</p>
<p>vasculhante</p>
<p>poblema</p> 
<p>pobrema</p>
<p>iorgute</p>
<p>mortandela</p>
<p>mendingo</p>
<p>mindingo</p>
<p>cardaço</p>
<p>alsicha</p>
<p>vinculando</p>
<p>reinterando</p>
<p>imperativo</p>

</div>
</div>

</center>
</body>
<script language="javascript">
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(antes, depois){
var palavra = this;
var posicao = palavra.indexOf(antes);

while (posicao > -1){
palavra = palavra.replace(antes, depois);
posicao = palavra.indexOf(antes);
}

return (palavra);
}
function corrigir(txt){
if(document.all.txt.value){
ler = {
'superfluo': {'por': 'superfulo'},
'locaute': {'por': 'nocaute'},
'gaviota': {'por': 'gaivota'},
'guspir': {'por': 'cuspir'},
'holoforte': {'por': 'holofote'},
'imbigo': {'por': 'umbigo'},
'luvem': {'por': 'nuvem'},
'estrupo': {'por': 'estupro'},
'bulancia': {'por': 'ambulância'},
'bassoura': {'por': 'vassoura'},
'encostamento': {'por': 'acostamento'},
'escangalo': {'por': 'escandalo'},
'helecoptro': {'por': 'helicóptero'},
'ebisódio': {'por': 'episódio'},
'camioneiro': {'por': 'caminhoneiro'},
'iplisom': {'por': 'ipsilon'},
'trabesseiro': {'por': 'travesseiro'}, 
'trabisseiro': {'por': 'travesseiro'},
'dico': {'por': 'pico'},
'repescagem': {'por': 'refrescagem'}, 
'garfanhoto': {'por': 'gafanhoto'},
'dibre': {'por': 'drible'},
'tauba' : {'por': 'tábua'},
'falcudade': {'por': 'faculdade'},
'experiênca': {'por': 'experiência'},
'asteristico': {'por': 'asterisco'},
'subaco': {'por': 'suvaco'},
'gumerangue': {'por': 'bumerangue'},
'tevelisão': {'por': 'televisão'},
'cisnei': {'por': 'cisney'},
'prosta': {'por': 'prostata'},
'resitro': {'por': 'registro'},
'sigura': {'por': 'segura'},
'fervereiro': {'por': 'fevereiro'},
'congustivel' : {'por': 'combustivel'},
'onégaro': {'por': 'orégano'},
'mictorio': {'por': 'nictorio'},
'degote': {'por': 'decote'},
'resistro': {'por': 'registro'},
'bigalha': {'por': 'migalha'},
'guspe': {'por': 'cuspe'},
'delatavam': {'por': 'dilatavam'},
'rejuvenescimento': {'por': 'rejuvelhecimento'},
'vasculante': {'por': 'basculante'},  
'vasculhante': {'por': 'basculante'}, 
'poblema': {'por': 'problema'},
'pobrema': {'por': 'problema'},
'iorgute': {'por': 'iogurte'},
'mortandela': {'por': 'mortadela'},
'mendingo': {'por': 'mendigo'},
'mindingo': {'por': 'mendigo'},
'cardaço': {'por': 'cadarço'},
'salsicha': {'por': 'salchicha'},
'vinculando': {'por': 'veiculando'},
'reinterando': {'por': 'reiterando'},
'imperativo': {'por': 'hiperativo'}
    };
}       
var resultado = document.all.txt.value;
for (var i in ler)
{
resultado = resultado.replaceAll(i,ler[i].por);
}
document.all.txt.value=resultado;
}
</script>
</html>
```

> Acho, que o código fonte em si é auto-explicativo, mas se houver qualquer dúvida comente!
>
> **IMPORTANTE!**  - Deixo claro que esta lista não foi construída e/ou modelada por minha pessoa, isso se deu após pesquisas sobre a diferença entre erro de ortografia e de gramática e afins. Cabendo aqui, ser meramente ilustrativo, `não sou formado em letras`. A real intenção é compartilha o que tenho questionado. Espero bom senso da parte de vocês.

Comment: "não é preciso de um dicionário". Na verdade, eu sugeriria usar um de verdade até para criar a lista. Na sua tem coisa certa sendo convertida pra errada, errada pra errada, certa pra outra certa, mas com outro sentido. Eu acho que como exercício, é legal seu código, mas na prática não vai funcionar, pelos motivos que já foram comentados pelo @user5978 na pergunta.