# Como fazer script auto-completa/incrementa

Tags: javascript, string, array, for

Houve a necessidade de se criar um campo texto que por ventura recebesse nomes de cidades, no entanto que completasse a palavra em campo ao iniciar os primeiros digítos.

Preciso de alguma idéia, *função* com `Arrays` literais, mais ou menos assim:

```
<script language="javascript">

function autocompletar()
{
cit = ["uberaba","araxa","colombia"];
str = document.all.txt.value;
for (var i in cit)
{
if (document.all.txt.value.length > 1)
{
str.match(document.all.txt.value=cit[i])
               {
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

> ***Dispenso Bibliotecas*** *nada pessoal, só não tenho interesse.*

Comment: Você precisa mesmo fazer isso no braço? Se não, aqui tem algumas implementações disso que você precisa: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ , https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom pessoal, fiz ...

> Primeiramente, cria-se um array, que terá a sua biblioteca compacta onde colocamos os dados que serão usados de forma sequencial.
>
> Logo depois, na *função* `autocompletar()`, defini que a cidade que queremos será uma das três que estiverem no array, e esse, por sua vez, será representado pela caixa de texto. Logo depois, já **no body**, basta **criar o campo de texto**, dando a essa, pelo *evento* `onKeyup`, a funcionalidade de execução da *função* `autocompletar()`.

```js
//criando objetos array 
sigla = new Object();
valor = new Object();

//declarando array com valores iniciais
  sigla[0] = 1000

//acessando um valor do array
//expecificado diretamente com o operador colchete
sigla[1] = "gua"; valor[1] = "guaíra"

sigla[2] = "bar"; valor[2] = "barretos"

sigla[3] = "mig"; valor[3] = "miguelópolis"
 
function autocompletar()
{
str = document.getElementById('txt').value;

//Iterando sobre aspas duplas de um objeto usando o for..in:
for (var i in sigla)
{

//Acessando o valor de um array através da aspas duplas
if(str.match(sigla[i]))
{

//recuperando os valores de um array entre as aspas duplas
str = document.getElementById('txt').value=valor[i];
           }
      }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="autocompletar()"/>
```

> Outra alternativa neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123521/como-substituir-corrigir-palavras-num-campo-de-texto), onde fiz algo parecido com este código acima, bastando somente adaptar e pronto!

Comment: E como é que vc vai preencher essa matriz? À mão?